# How to serves a react app with node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have always been wondering how React routing works in a single page app. For example, when I wanna go to https://example.com/a . How does it know "a" is a React route in example.com, and doesn't attempt to go to https://example.com/a/ which doesn't exist.

Now I have a problem with that. I created a single page React app with routing. And host the built version with node.js with the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build_webpack')));
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on ' + port);
})
```

When I go to localhost:3000, and navigate to localhost:3000/route within the app, it works fine. However, if I type localhost:3000/route in the browser and hit enter. There is an error complaining about:

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security
Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set,
so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."
```

Which is the same error I get when attempting to visit a route that doesn't exist: localhost:3000/routeThatDoesntExist.

I think the problem might be how I server the app with node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the server to send `index.html` on any route it encounters.

For eg:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

[Create React App Docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

Comment: Thanks. But for some reasons, that doesn't work. The express.static middleware somehow catches the subroutes. I had to use app.use(function(req,res){res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));}); And now it works.